# recover a pickle corrupted file after getting OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: python, pickle, eoferror

i'm kind of stuck here, i tried to look for an existing solution but couldn't find anything.

So the issue i have is this :

having a python script gathering data. At some point the disk of the server is full (my bad ...) so when the script tried to pickle.dump the last data gathered it crash and gave :

> OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Now i can't pickle.load the data, when i try to do so it gave me

> _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
>   or
>   EOFError: Ran out of input

so i'd like to know if there is a way to open it anyways to backup the good data in there. Or is my previous data is gone :(

btw the pickle file is ~700kB

Comment: i tried to do so, but getting IndexError, or when i try to catch also the IndexError exception the unpickler.stack give me `[<function _create_filehandle at 0x10afb17b8>, ('./pathtopickle', 'wb', 0, False, <built-in function open>, False, 0, '')] `

Comment: If your disk is still full, of course you can't write anything.

Comment: But it's not, and i also tried on my osx laptop

Comment: The `wb` looks like you are opening a file for writing. I can't really guess how you produced that error message.

Comment: sorry i post the wrong output, but it gives me the same result with 'rb' `[<function _create_filehandle at 0x109da8e18>, ('./pathtopickle', 'rb', 0, False, <built-in function open>, False, 0, '')]`